# Two function with independent variable

Tags: partial-differential-equations

$h(x)=g(y)$ where x and y  are independent variable then $h(x)=C=g(y)$ (This is related to partial differentiable equation solution by variable separation)

I cannot get point that two function is equal if and only if they are constant how is it true? got confused please help ?

Answer (score 0):

If $h(x)=g(y)$ for all real $x$ and $y$, then in particular $h(x)=g(0)$ for all real $x$. That is, $h(x)=C$ for all real $x$, where $C=g(0)$. That is, $h$ is a constant function, with constant we call $C$.  And in particular, $h(0)=C$.  Now look at $h(0)=g(y)$, for all real $y$.  So $g$ is also the same constant function.

Answer (score 0):

Think about it, if you have two functions, of *two* different variables, let them take on different values, e.g. $h\left(x_1\right)$ and $h\left(x_2\right)$ *and* $g\left(y_1\right)$ and $g\left(y_2\right)$. You know that $h_1 = g_1 = h_2 = g_2$ because you're told that that $h(x) = g(y)$ regardless of the value of $x$ or $y$.

**Intuition:**

If you can change the value of $x$, you can change the value of $h(x)$ thus breaking the equality. Therefore, changing the value of $x$ must *not* change the value of $h(x)$ (and likewise for $g(y)$). If the value cannot change, the function is a constant.

**Proof by Contradiction:**

Assume you have found an equality, an $x_1$ and $y_1$ such that $g\left(x_1\right) = h\left(y_1\right)$. Choose another point such that $g\left(x_2\right) \neq g\left(x_1\right)$, now we have $g\left(x_2\right) \neq h\left(y_1\right)$, a contradiction. You can do the same for $y$. The contradiction indicates that for any two points, $x_1$ and $x_2$, $g\left(x_1\right) = g\left(x_2\right)$ and likewise $h\left(y_1\right) = h\left(y_2\right)$.

**Concrete Example:** *(But still weird)*

Let's say you have two step-wise functions:

$$
h(x) = \begin{cases}
-1& x < 0\\
1& x \geq 0
\end{cases}
$$

$$
g(y) = \begin{cases}
-1& y < 0\\
1& y \geq 0
\end{cases}
$$

These functions are the same no?

No, they're not equal: $h(-1) \neq g(1)$. If you can find a pair of values unequal in the image of the the two functions then you can make them unequal, meaning the only way for them to always be equal is for them to be a constant value *all* of the time.